# .Net C# : Read attachment from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, attachment, httpwebresponse

Is it possible to read an image attachment from `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`?

I have a url to a java page, which generates images.

When I open the url in firefox, the download dialog appears. Content-type is application/png.
Seems to work.

When I try this in c#, and make a GET request I retrieve the content-type: text/html and no content-disposition header.

Simple Code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

`response.GetResponseStream()` is empty.

A try with java was successful.

Do I have to prepare webrequest or something else?

Comment: It isn't called an attachment.

Comment: @SLaks, then what is it called? You would be so much more helpful if you said what it was called instead.

Comment: @Deantwo: It doesn't have a fixed name.  Image, URL, request?

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to set a User-Agent header.

Run [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) and compare the requests.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 1):

Writing something in the [`UserAgent` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent) of the `HttpWebRequest` does indeed make a difference in a lot of cases. A common practice for web services seem to be to ignore requests with an empty `UserAgent`.
See: [Webmasters: Interpretation of empty User-agent](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/35642/103078)

Simply set the `UserAgent` property to a non-empty `string`. You can for example use the name of your application, assembly information, impersonate a [common UserAgent](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_type_specific/web-browser/), or something else identifying.

Examples:

```
request.UserAgent = "my example program v1";
```

```
request.UserAgent = $"{System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToString()} v{System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()}";
```

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36";
```

And just to give a full working example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

void DownloadFile(Uri uri, string filename)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Timeout = 10000;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.UserAgent = "my example program v1";
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(filename))
            {
                receiveStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```